# Find exact words in a string for a range of words in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to find whether a string contains a range of 'exact words' in excel. eg:

```
A                                    B          C           D              E (Output)
Apple is a large company            App        IOS      App Store           Software
```

If a string under column **"A"** contains any of the EXACT words on column **B:D**, the output should be column "E".

I currently have a formula that looks like:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1:D1,A1)))>0,E1,"")
```

The issue is that it doesn't search for EXACT words; so **"App"** would be picked up by **"Apple"**.

I could amend the SEARCH so that each of the columns **B,C,D** are searched separately, but was wondering if there was an easier way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add spaced to the front and back:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&B1:D1&" "," "&A1&" ")))>0,E1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked well :) Any online sources you could point me to for explanation so I can look at it further plz?

Comment: The problem is, if the word is the first or last in a cell, it won't have a leading or trailing space, so it won't find the word.

Comment: @ZviTwersky that is why there is a `" "` at the beginning and the end of both references in the SEARCH, so it does not matter.